# Why am I getting a doubled menu when I click the link for my main page?

Tags: html, visual-studio

Whenever I click the "Home" option on my menu (left hand side, frames), a second copy of the menu page appears on the left side of the main window. The html of this link is identical to the other links, which work fine. As I'm just developing the site at the moment, the HTML of all the links is also identical. There is no code difference between this link and the others in any way, only the behavior.

The doubled copy of the menu is a phantom. It will not double itself again, and goes away when any other link, other than the home page, is navigated to. I'm currently in school and this is my first ground-up project, so I'm sure it's something stupid and simple.

Comment: can you use jsfiddle to give us something to see and mess around with to help you?

Comment: Googling jsfiddle. So... possibly.

Comment: Okay, think I have a vague idea of how this works. Here's the menu. http://jsfiddle.net/pqaV6/

Comment: And here's the index page. http://jsfiddle.net/pqaV6/1/

Comment: You need to put valid css, html and js into jsfiddle, an example: http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/fdavn/ try to simulate your problems there so that we can advice you further

Comment: I click on the link and get the full html and css. There is no js at the moment. Well, okay, the index.aspx link has the wrong css with it, but it has nothing on it that's affected by it... in fact I think I'll take the css link out...

Comment: from the fiddle, i cant simulate your problem, you don't have to make it look all pretty and nice, just a mock-up to replicate your problem will do

Comment: I have no idea how to get the multiple pages active at the same time I'd need to get that to work. I did solve the problem though. It was definitely something stupid and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Aarron, your problem is indeed quite obvious. After looking for hours, the solution the whole time is that your "Home" link is pointed at Index.aspx, which is the page with your frames, instead of Main.aspx. You were thinking of Index as your home page, which it is, but linking there in this context gave you frames within frames, instead of the default opening display page you were aiming for.

Comment: glad that you found your own answer